# jQuery autocomplete - Fill input regardless if JSON result is not yet ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

I have got a large database of products that i search through with an input that uses jQuery `.autocomplete()` function. The products are being searched by name or ID. When the list with items appear, the user can select a product from the list to populate the input with the product-ID and some of the other fields with known predefined values like 'taxes' or 'productName'. Layout is like this:

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="text" id="productID" />
<input type="text" id="productName" />
<input type="text" id="quantity" />
<input type="text" id="taxes" />

... and more relative inputs

<input type="text" id="price" />
<!-- add product to cart -->
<input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
```

The meaning of the form is to insert products to a certain shopcart while manually filling unknown or alternating known fields.

Now the thing is that I know many product-ID's by memory and can type them straight away, so I can quickly adjust the necessary fields and hit 'ENTER' to insert the product in the cart. The problem is that when I leave the `.autocomplete()` field, the list with results disappears and doesn't select a product.

**My jQuery**

```
var cache = {};
$("#productID").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function (request, response) {
        var term = request.term; // search-term
        // check if the term is already cached
        if (term in cache) {
            response(cache[ term ]); // return cached result
            return;
        }
        // get results from remote script
        $.getJSON("/autocomplete.php", request, function (data) {
            cache[ term ] = data; // cache the result for this term
            response(data);
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        // pre-populate fields of the product
        $("#productName").val(ui.item.name);
        $("#taxes").val(ui.item.taxes);
        $("#price").val(ui.item.price);
    }
};
```

Here, I need to wait for the response to show and then press 'TAB' to select the product.

Is there any way to let the JSON response continue when I 'TAB' out off the field, and that it selects the first item in the list? As this is pretty straight-forward work, I don't like waiting for the response to show everytime to select a product.

## EDIT

Found the solution thanks to @raduation! Here is what I did:

```
// first altered the autocomplete-select to point to a Js-function
var cache = {};
$("#productID").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function (request, response) {
        var term = request.term; // search-term
        // check if the term is already cached
        if (term in cache) {
            response(cache[ term ]); // return cached result
            return;
        }
        // get results from remote script
        $.getJSON("/autocomplete.php", request, function (data) {
            cache[ term ] = data; // cache the result for this term
            response(data);
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        // pre-populate fields of the product
        selectValueAutocomplete(ui.item, $(this));
    }
};

// function to insert item's values in the fields
function selectValueAutocomplete(item, input)
{
    input.val(item.value);
    $("#productName").val(item.name);
    $("#taxes").val(item.taxes);
    $("#price").val(item.price);
}
```

And I added Eventlisteners to check what to do when focussed or not:

```
$(document)
    .on("focusout", "#productID", function() {
        $(this).addClass("selectFirst");
    })
    .on("focus", "#productID", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("selectFirst");
     }) // Here I invoke the jQuery.autocomplete()'s response event
    .on("autocompleteresponse", "#productID", function( event, ui ) {
        if($(this).hasClass("selectFirst"))
        { // select first item from response
            selectValueAutocomplete(ui.content[0], $(this));
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a key event listener on the text input field, that listens for a Tab key.   Once the Tab key is pressed, set a property on the text input that means "populate with first product match".  For example: `$('#productId').prop('populateFirst',true);`

Then, in your getJSON callback function, check for the presence of this property, and populate the first product.  After this is done (or if there is an ajax error), delete the property, so it doesn't interfere with the next use of the autocomplete.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it steered me in the right direction but I still don't know how to invoke the method that selects the first option of the list with results.. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Move the statements in the `select` function into a separate function and call that function from the `getJSON` callback.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I added a class on focusout, and remove the class on focus, and used the jquery autocomplete documentation to trigger the response that comes from the JSON. See my EDIT :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you don't simply specify `autocomplete.php` in the source option ?

```
$("#productID").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: "autocomplete.php"
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        // pre-populate fields of the product
        $("#productName").val(ui.item.name);
        $("#taxes").val(ui.item.taxes);
        $("#price").val(ui.item.price);
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/7mbuuauc/).... It is supposed to works.
*(I simulated the source, of course... But should work the same.)*

Comment: I already tried, but first of all I need to provide a search-term, and based on that, I receive a response from the query to the database in the script

Comment: `name`, `taxes` and `price` anren't already in your json produced by autocomplete.php?

Comment: Yes, they are, but they are related to the results which comes from the query. Each product has its own price and taxes set, so I need to search the database for the results to return, and only those that match with the term. I'm not really sure about what you are suggesting, though.

Comment: Could you show an example of the autocomplete.php resulting json ? To see how it is structured ?

Comment: When i fill in a term like 'sample', the JSON response will look like this:

`[
    {
        "id": "4000001", 
        "value": "4000001", 
        "label": "4000001 - SampleProduct1", 
        "price": "27.75", 
        "name": "Product 1", 
        "taxes": "10%"
    },
    {
        "id": "4000002", 
        "value": "4000002", 
        "label": "4000002 - SampleProduct2", 
        "price": "12.55", 
        "name": "Product 2", 
        "taxes": "10%"
    }
]`